# add string array values into dynamo db

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm trying to use put_item to add an array of strings into dynamodb.

This is the code that I wrote:

```
table = dynamodb.Table('variables')
string = [first line, second line, third line]

table.put_item(
    Item = {
        "variables": { "SS": [ string ]}
    }
)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

"errorMessage": "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key strings in the item"

I've tried reading through the documentation but without luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Table` resource, you don't need to specify DynamoDB types like `SS`. Just put your item into `dict`, otherwise you will see these types being interpreted as actual data.

There is a bit of confusion between `client.put_item()` which expects raw data with types, and `Table.put_item()` which expects regular dict. Whenever possible, use table one.

In your case it should look something like `table.put_item(Item = {"variables": string})`

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: @Guido Then you maybe need to update the question with full code snippet